# Symfony attribute expects a integer, but got string error

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to do my own authentication class.

Here is my User entity.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length="11")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="25")
     */
    protected $login;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="25")
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="25")
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="25")
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="25")
     */
    protected $email;

    public function getId()
    {
    return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
    return $this->login;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
    return $this->password;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
    return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
    return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
    return $this->email;
    }

    public function setLogin($login)
    {
    $this->login = $login;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
    $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
    $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

And the security settings (just like in docs)

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: login }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /account/check
                login_path: /account/login
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I am getting next error - [Type Error] Attribute "length" of @ORM\Column declared on property AppBundle\Entity\User::$id expects a(n) integer, but got string.

Im not sure i can understand the error. From where it got string? I dont even have anything in users table.

I would like to ask you to help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing it a string by enclosing it in quotes. I'm suspect you think it's similar to HTML where you *do* need to enclose attributes in quotes - that is not the case here:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=11)
     */
    protected $id;

//...
}
```

Apply this change everything you used `length="11"`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong type should be integer and you don't need the length. So something like

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;
```